# When (if ever) should [solidity] programming questions be considered off-topic and migrated to stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, moderation, topic

Are all solidity oriented questions `on-topic` by virtue of being about the programming language that `Ethereum` uses?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I think all questions about Solidity are on-topic as said by OP.

When this ESE (Ethereum Stack Exchange) graduates, if a relationship is set with stackoverflow, I believe that Solidity questions on SO can be migrated to ESE: [Will it be possible to migrate questions between the trilogy and the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-questions-between-the-trilogy-and-the-stack-exchan)

Comment: I concur, it is definitely a matter of size of ESE and Ethereum, and i predict solidity will be a main driver for this community. So let's encourage such questions.

Comment: What about questions that seems to be oop related and not even linked to Solidity as http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/5726/405 ?

Comment: @NicolasMassart imo the question is fine, but it should be edited/improved with something about Solidity as the asker says in the comments...  That way, some answers will also include at least some relevant part to Solidity

Comment: @eth but if someone asks "what a variable is used for in Solidity ?" Is it also on topic? For me it's the same type of question an putting the word Solidity in the question doesn't force it to be relevant for this SE site.

Comment: @NicolasMassart I agree "variable" would not be on-topic. imo there's enough with interface question that when someone writes a more detailed answer, it will be clearer to see the relevance.  imo A better answer should at least mention import; how solc processes a file with multiple interface/contracts; and it could explain why thedao does what it does.  I have to check the details so haven't posted an answer.

Comment: @eth OK, but question must be improved first. As it's for now it just asks what the benefit of having an interface is. This is not Solidity scope. So I will try to edit the question first.

Answer (score 2):

Yes solidity is always considered on-topic, even if used in other context, since it's central part of the ethereum ecosystem.

In the future, if there are ecosystems using modified solidity implementations which are not backwards compatible with ethereum, we could reconsider if such questions are off topic.

But for now there is really no point in migrating solidity questions to stack overflow. Should we add solidity to the [tour page](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/tour)?